# Setting correct Content-Type sent from Wordpress, on Apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, http-headers

I need help pointing me in the right direction for setting the `ContentType` returned by Apache for content produced by WordPress. I'm having trouble figuring out why WordPress is returning incorrect headers.

### Issue

The specific problem is that our Wordpress blog pages **are being downloaded as a file** rather than displayed by Internet Explorer and Chrome v21.

`Content-Type: application/x-gzip` is being returned by the server.

I'm told that I should expect `Content-Type: text/html`.

### Background

The URL is http://www.bitesizeirishgaelic.com/blog/.

Comment: If you have access, post (and/or examine) your apache confs for any setting referencing `/blog`.

Comment: Hmm, the `httpd.conf` doesn't mention `blog`.

Comment: Mm ... could there be a WP plugin causing this ... ? Look at this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/visit-my-site-and-it-tries-to-download-a-gz-file

Comment: I don't think so, as I tested with all plugins turned off. Adding my own answer below for the record.

Answer (score 0):

My host helped solve this in the end:

> The most common causes for this behavior is an issue with the PHP handler or the AddHandler variable in an .htaccess file. I reset your PHP handler to suPHP, which it already was set to, and restarted Apache. That resolved the issue.